# How to get blooming effect in cycles without compositing

Tags: materials, emission

How to achieve bloom effect for a emission material in **cycles** . I want to do it without compositing [image]As shown in the picture there is an emission material (blue in color) Is there any way to achieve this without compositing?

Comment: Hello :). Bloom (in Eevee) is a faked light diffusion. To get the same effect in Cycles you'd need to add some volumetric fog.

Comment: Thank a lot but I can't use it in this since i have a 8k HDRi and it is impossible for my potato PC to handle. Not that I even knew about it to get something like this.

Comment: yes Volume Scatter or Principled Volume are a bit heavy, faking it with Layer Weight is the solution for potato computers  ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jachym Michal says you can create a box with volumetric. A lighter solution is to fake the glowing with a ***Layer Weight/Facing*** node:

- Create your object.
- Create a sphere that contains your object (here displayed as wireframe) and give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to make it smooth.
- Give it the following material, which is a mix between *Emission* (with the color of your cube) and *Transparent*, with the *Layer Weight* as *Factor* in the *Mix Shader*.

[image]

- Of course you can increase the *Emission' Strength*. Also the node organization can be improved with a second *Mix Shader* to add more transparency, or you can control the *Layer Weight* with a *ColorRamp*, or add noise, etc... And you can scale the sphere on whatever axis you want if the object is a long one.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank a lot but can you explain why there is an empty and how to use it  and to increase the intensity of the effect what should i do? It works for me perfectly.

Comment: there is no empty, it's a sphere that I've created that contains the cube, I've disaplayed the sphere as wireframe to make it clear, the material belongs to this sphere, the cube material is just made of an Emission node.

Comment: What do you mean by "increase the intensity"? You can increase the Emission Strength if necessary, or give more transparency with another Mix Shader, etc...

Comment: I got a ball of light when I did what you said

Comment: it's a fake scattering so you can play with all the factors of your nodes like Emission strength, transparency, sphere size, etc... does it achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: yes but it is too much glow even with the strength at 1 its not that transparent with all that light

Comment: you can add a second Mix Shader in order to mix the current one with a new Transparent node if you want the halo to be lighter... there are a lot of possibilities... Take a look at my edit

Comment: Solved it sorry I accidently changed the emission of another material when i reduceed the emission of the fake scattering material it works perfectly .Thanks a lot

Comment: also you can control the Layer Weight with a ColorRamp (see my edit again), etc......

Comment: I would've never thought of using a layer weight node here, but this is simply brilliant :).

Comment: I work on a Macboorkpro which is not the best for 3D, so I guess I need to find some other way around   ;)   I'll have a better one soon, I hope, so I'll be able to switch to the latest versions of Blender, I'm looking forward to discovering Eevee